# How to remove selected row only from a material table mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to remove the selected row only in mat-table. Please find the stackblitz link here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzh8g4?file=app/table-basic-example.ts

I tried somehow but not working.

```
remove(val) {
console.log(val);
this.dataSource.splice(this.dataSource.indexOf(val), 1);}
```

Comment: One reason is that val is not what you think it is. It is a *MouseEvent*

Comment: So.. change in html `(click)="remove(element)"` and add `this.dataSource = [...this.dataSource];` after you splice the array, and it will work. Basically you have to reinitialize the source array for that mat-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `MatTableDataSource`

and set your `remove` function

```
remove(element) {
    this.dataSource.data.splice(ELEMENT_DATA.indexOf(element),1);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(this.dataSource.data);
}
```

And online application [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzh8g4-anjm3x)

Answer (score 1):

You will need an immutable operation for that:

```
this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter(item => item !== val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
remove(element) {
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(item => item !== element)
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IUser>(this.dataSource.data);
}
```

Comment: I tried without the second line and it works,  is there a particular reason to have it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `renderRows()` function of MatTable like below to update your table.

**Typescript**

```js
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'action'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  @ViewChild('table') table:MatTable<any>;
  remove(val) {
    console.log(val);
    this.dataSource.splice(this.dataSource.indexOf(val), 1);
    this.table.renderRows();
  }
```

**Html**

```html
<!-- table tag -->
<table #table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

....

<!-- remove Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <a (click)="remove(element)">Remove</a> </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Also make sure you are passing column value in remove function instead of event